# Como dejar por default un option

Tags: angular

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una grilla en la cual tengo un select, dicha grilla se utiliza en varios componentes por lo cual uso un [(ngModel)], al utilizar el [(ngModel)] no puedo dejar mi option por default, siempre me viene en blanco

```
    <select (selectionChange)="selectTipoDocumento($event.value ,  asegurado.Nro )"
      [attr.required]="asegurado.flTipoDocumentoRequerido" [(ngModel)]="asegurado.TipoDocumento"
      [readonly]="!asegurado.tipoDocumentoEditable">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Tipo Doc</option>
      <option [value]="td.codigoDocumento" *ngFor="let td of tiposDocumento"
        [selected]="td.codigoDocumento === asegurado.TipoDocumento">
        {{ td.descripcion }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: En tu primer <option> tienes value="" y por eso te sale en blanco, ¿intentaste poner el valor por default que quieres ahí?, o tal vez no estoy entendiendo muy bien que es lo que quieres

Comment: Lo que yo busco es que "Tipo Doc" se visualice por default en pantalla, entiendo que si dejo value vacio tendria que posicionarse en esa posicion automaticamente,

Comment: Si saco el [(ngModel)] cumple el funcionamiento que busco, pero pierdo la comunicacion entre componentes que es lo que tambien necesito